# Multiplayer Mobile Game on Azure

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, appwarp

I want to make a multiplayer game on Windows Phone 8/8.1. I want to create dynamic game rooms and allow users to join and play my game online. I've tried AppWarp, but windows phone silverlight wont reference the dll file. Any idea how can i make my own Azure service to handle all of these ??

Comment: AppWarp already supports WP 8/8.1. It has SDK for both WP .Net SDK and WinRT. What is the issue with AppWarp?

Comment: i downloaded the dll for wp7/8 , any wp8 project can reference it but the typical wp8 silverlight template is unable to reference it

**A reference to higher or incompatible assembly**

Answer (score 1):

Did you try unblocking the assembly?Most of the times the assemblies we download are blocked for security purposes.You can unblock your dll by right clicking on the dll,then go to properties,click on advanced option and hit the unblock button.Now retry to refer the dll.

Comment: Thanks a ton !! it worked. Cant wait to get started.